# Background color of a button changes on mobile

Tags: html, css

I would like a button to be colored orange and show only when a user visits the site on a smartphone.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .belnummobiel {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0) !important;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 451px) {
  .belnummobiel {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the button shouldn't show on desktop versions of the website, which works.

The weird thing is that the orange background doesn't show on Android Chrome browsers, but does show when you scale a desktop browser to a mobile size, any thoughts?

Comment: Thats because that css rule doesn't say anything about mobile devices. It just targets the screen size. So if you are on the desktop with a smaller browserwidth than 451px then you see the button.

If you want to detect mobile devices you can either to that with JS and append a class to the body on which you react. Or do the same on the server and apply given class to the body as you render the page.

Comment: css can't detect agents...yet. Your media query simply determines the genre of media, not specificity of it. See the docs: `screen` = __Used for computer screens, tablets, smart-phones etc.__

Comment: What is displayed instead of the orange color? Is it blue? Does it always have that color, or only when you tap it?

Comment: Just a white text, like the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your media query, because the query what have taken that won't support for the current android mobiles. currently you have written for max-width 450, so may be where you are checking that devices will support when it max-width 480. You try below code , so it will support for both potrait and landscape of android browser and will hide for desktop.

```
.belnummobiel {
display: none !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { 
.belnummobiel {
color: #fff;
background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0) !important;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display:block
}
```

Comment: Your css doesn't check for mobiles either, it just has a different screen size threshold.